# Some space between divs in line

Tags: html, html-table

I want to build 'rubber' interface, so I use div with width in %, but when I try to fill 100% of width with several divs, they not intermix on line, but in suome they have 100%. If use table then all fine. Here are examples:

```
<div style='white-space:nowrap;'>
    <div style='width:50%;border: 1px solid #4e5e6e;display:inline-table;'>A1</div>
    <div style='width:50%;border: 1px solid #a2f2d4;display:inline-table;'>A2</div>
</div>
<div style='white-space:nowrap;'>
    <div style='width:10%;border: 1px solid #4e5e6e;float:left'>A1</div>
    <div style='width:40%;border: 1px solid #a2f2d4;float:left'>A2</div>
    <div style='width:40%;border: 1px solid #4e5e6e;float:left'>A3</div>
    <div style='width:10%;border: 1px solid #a2f2d4;float:left'>A4</div>
</div>
<table style='width:100%'><tr style="width:100%";>
    <td style='width:10%;border: 1px solid #4e5e6e;'>A1</td>
    <td style='width:40%;border: 1px solid #4e5e6e;'>A1</td>
    <td style='width:40%;border: 1px solid #4e5e6e;'>A1</td>
    <td style='width:10%;border: 1px solid #4e5e6e;'>A1</td>
</td></table>
```

If size of you window is enough, they all will appear right, but if you make it smaller, someone jump off their line.
If I do not clearly expressed, I want to display div in a single line in not depending on the width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1px border adds to the width of the boxes. So your boxes will have a width of 50%+1px, 10%+1px and so on.

Answer (score 2):

the solution would be to remove the pixel from the border and put a div inside the % width div with a border

Answer (score 2):

What lucassp said.

A solution would be to add a negative margin to anything you gave a border:

```
<td style='width:10%;border: 1px solid #4e5e6e; margin: -1px;'>A1</td>
```